# How do I use a CanActivateFn to hide a link?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, canactivate

I am using `CanActivateFn` rather than `CanActivate` to handle my routing authentication.

Here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ExampleTableComponent } from './example-table/example-table.component';
import { authGuard } from '../_guards/auth.guard';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SearchComponent} from './search/search.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'example-table', component: ExampleTableComponent, canActivate: [authGuard] },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [authGuard] },
    { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here's my auth.guard.ts:

```
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs';
import { EndpointService } from 'projects/lib/xp-endpoints/endpoint.service';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
    const endpointService: EndpointService = inject(EndpointService)
    const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService)
    const _snackBar: MatSnackBar = inject(MatSnackBar)
    const router: Router = inject(Router)

    return authService.PAS.pipe(
        map(pasArray => {
           /* Auth stuff */
           return false
        })
    )
};
```

Here's an example of the link I have displaying:

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngIf="Something here that removes the link if the user doesn't have access">
    <a routerLink="/search"><button>Search</button></a>
</div>
```

What's happening right now is if the user doesn't have access they can still view the link. I'd like the link to be removed from the page completely.

Comment: Take a look at solutions provided in this github [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25342).

Comment: Please create a custom directive to hide and show links on the basis of authorization.

Comment: What do you mean @Shahrukh ? Are you talking about where I left the comment  /* Auth stuff */ ?

Comment: No, on the div where you're adding the *ngIf you can simply create a directive and apply it. This will help you https://juristr.com/blog/2018/02/angular-permission-directive

Comment: How do I call `authGuard` in that directive? What you're asking me to do is the thing I don't know and the whole premise of my question.

Comment: If you know exactly which guard you want to check, you can just import that guard into the component, because it's just a function. So it won't check if the link can be activated, but it will check if the authGuard fails or not.

Comment: Could you show an example please @Tortila?

Comment: In .ts: `route = inject(ActivatedRouteSnapshot); state = inject(RouterStateSnapshot); isSearchShown$ = authGuard(route, state);` In .html: `*ngIf="isSearchShown$ | async"` You may even omit injecting route and state if you don't use them in authGuard.